# How to connect a client and a server?

Tags: c++, udp

Even if UDP is connection-less, I would like to establish some kind of connection between a client and a server.
The thing is, once the server has received something from the client, the only thing I can do send my answer is use the IP and the Port from the client.

And well... this will, in almost EVERY CASE, not be the IP of the client, because the client doesn't have an IP on the Internet : only its router does.
I would like to know how to send back data to the client, even if he's behind a router.

I'm starting to believe it's impossible... but it MUST BE possible : don't tell me videogames use UDP only for sending data from a client to a server !

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something like [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send back to the client through the same socket, the NAT will automagically resolve that and pass it on to the actual box.

Comment: Seems quite simple o_O !
I was actually wondering that because me and some friends wondered : assuming that we have two computers from the same sub-network connected to our server... on the server-side, they have the same IP, and are listening on the same port : how will the NAT know which one of them the server is talking to ?
Will it send it back to the last computer who sent something to the server ? In that case, unless we're very carefull, we may send extra-package to a client, and nothing to the other.
If you just tell me it'll work, I can go with it. But I'm curoius about it ^^ !

Comment: @The-Snake: Part of what NAT does is change the originating port numbers for outgoing packets to your server. Even if your clients both think they are listening on the same port number, the server will see *different* port numbers.

Comment: I had no idea, this is awesome ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Options for UDP behind firewalls:

1. Explicit rules on the firewall/NAT forwarding UDP packets to a particular machine.
2. UPnP to setup the rules automatically (from the client end)
3. Automatic return path for UDP - NAT remembers ports and IP addresses, and creates a return rule for UDP packets.

Answer (score 0):

Your router will notice that it's rewritten an outgoing data packet to look as if it came from a port on the router, and remember that. If it then receives a UDP packet address to that same port it will say "Oh, I know where to send this!" and forward it on to the port on the inside of the network that original data came from.

usually the router remembers routes for a certain time then forgets them if it doesn't see anything on that port.